# Selecting elements that aren't the :target selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors, target

I'm attempting to make a simple blog style website using one XML, one XSLT, and one CSS.
For that I'd like to have the option to only view one entry from the xml, and I would like to do it without javascript or php.
I'm trying to do this using the :target selector.

The behaviour I would like to achieve would be;

- index.html should show everything
- index.html#one should only show the entry with id="one"
- index.html#two should only show the entry with id="two"

and so on.

I've found solutions that will display the last sibling, however that doesn't fit. My xslt turns entries into tables, and I can't see how I dynamically could parse the xml to fit that solution.

Is there a way to do this with css, or should I start learning php?

Comment: `.entry:not(:target)`

Comment: Tried wracking my brain on how to use the :not selector, and I can't seem to find the right way to do it. I would love to select div:target+div:not(:target) (select all the sibling divs that aren't the target), however it only selects the divs after, not the ones before. If that makes sense :<

Comment: Add a class to your div, then select not by element name, but by class name. And yes, there is no "previous sibling" selector in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

this should be an either/or proposition ... learn PHP. it will benefit you.

but for a CSS-only solution (with a little .htaccess magic) you could do a rewrite of index.html to index.html#all, set your wrapping div to have ID of all (or whatever your wrapper ID is), then set the :target CSS for #all to show everything.

```
#all .YouWantToHide {
    display:none;
}

#all:target .YouWantToHide, #one:target, #two:target {
    display:block;
}
```

This will hide everything by default on the normal page (which will never be visited, it just sets the tone for the specific items to show and other to hide later), show on the #all target (which is now the default page), and the specific items will show as needed while the others will hide.

Comment: And have the .htaccess redirect to index.hml#all?
I've managed to do that, but without the htaccess it hid everything with no target in the url. I'll look into htaccess, and try that, thanks!

Comment: Yup, without that htaccess rewrite it wont work. once you have that set up, though, it should be smooth.

Comment: I tried a simple (as far as I can tell) "redirect /index.htm /index.htm#all", however that gave me a 500 internal server error. Tried changing permissions to 0644 but that didn't help. Any tips would be greatly appreaciated :D (Host is awardspace).

Comment: sorry, i should have known better ... hashtags are client-side, not server-side. you would need to use javascript even to do the solution that i proposed. :(